# Subtracting time from current time

Tags: javascript, node.js, if-statement

I have 2 strings, that have the `minute` and `hour` that a function needs to occur at.

I want to check, if the `minute` and `hour` which are specified in string format, and from my database are within 5 minutes of the current time, call this function.

My original thought was something like:

(today.minute is the current minute)

`today.minute`:

```
minute = "55"
hour = "14"
var today = new Date();
var time = today.getMinutes(), today.getHours()

if (today.getMinutes() - 5 == minute) {
   myFunc()
}
```

But that isn't going to work, because I need the hour and minute - 5 minutes... how can I do this?

Comment: if(today.getHours()*60+today.getMinutes() - 5 == parseInt(hour)*60+parseInt(minute))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```js
let minute = "55"
let hour = "14"
let today = new Date();
//var time = today.getMinutes(), today.getHours()

if (Math.abs(today.getMinutes() - Number(minute)) <= 5) {
   myFunc()
}

function myFunc() {
  console.log('myFunc called', today.getMinutes());
 }
```